# How to refactor C# linq code?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, refactoring

I've created a console application that is using LinqToSql.  It works very well, but I feel that it is a code smell.  Here's my linq query:

```
var personnelInfo = Personnels.Where(p => p.Name.Equals("Steve Jobs"));
```

Now, I want to report on various fields of that object.  This is what I feel is a code smell:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Emp ID = {0}", personnelInfo.Select(p => p.EmpID).FirstOrDefault()));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Phone# = ({0}) {1}-{2}", 
    personnelInfo.Select(p => p.Phone).FirstOrDefault().Substring(0,3),
    personnelInfo.Select(p => p.Phone).FirstOrDefault().Substring(3,3),
    personnelInfo.Select(p => p.Phone).FirstOrDefault().Substring(6,4)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("City = {0}", personnelInfo.Select(p => p.City).FirstOrDefault()));
```

Can this be refactored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the query result just once:

```
var firstPerson = personnelInfo.First();
```

You can then access properties directly.

You should also move the phone number formatting into a separate re-usable function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a foreach as there might be another Steve Jobs out there:

```
foreach(var personel in personelInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Emp ID = {0}", personel.EmpID));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Phone# = ({0}) {1}-{2}", 
        personel.Phone.Substring(0,3),
        personel.Phone.Substring(3,3),
        personel.Phone.FirstOrDefault().Substring(6,4)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("City = {0}", personel.City));
}
```